# CredDB.CEF not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, filenotfoundexception

I am getting this error on running a C# project

```
Could not find file 'C:\*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*\bin\ar\CredDB.CEF'.
```

This is happening in multiple projects. Not much help is available online regarding this issue. Does anybody has an idea?

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*\bin\ar\CredDB.CEF'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +519
   System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length() +12977229
   System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddExistingFile(String fileName) +171
   System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddDirectory(String directoryName) +302
   System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddDirectory(String directoryName) +369
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +352
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549

[HttpException (0x80004005): 'C:\*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*\bin\ar\CredDB.CEF'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10075124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Update:

Dell Encryption Tool was pre-installed in the laptop and after a windows update, it started behaving inappropriately. On tracking the encryption logs, got to know that the shield service is not properly starting on the endpoint:

```
[03.12.19 13:40:57:329       NTUtils.cpp: 1555 E] [SUPPORT] [E] The Shield service is not running!  Attempting to restart. Current service state = 1
```

Upgrading the Dell Encryption resolved the problem.

> If you are a Dell Employee, and this is happening with you, raise an incident under Service Now and select DDPE as Application.

Comment: Do you have a Dell Encryption tool installed on your machine?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes. I am working in Dell itself. So Dell Encryption has always been there. But this is happening from last 2 weeks.

Comment: I'm having this also trying to use Gradle. It started happening today. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: This Error is Most likely caused by Dell Encryption. Suggest you to raise a Service-Now Request to get this resolved internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell Encryption Tool was pre-installed in the laptop and after a windows update, it started behaving inappropriately. On tracking the encryption logs, got to know that the shield service is not properly starting on the endpoint:

```
[03.12.19 13:40:57:329       NTUtils.cpp: 1555 E] [SUPPORT] [E] The Shield service is not running!  Attempting to restart. Current service state = 1
```

Upgrading the Dell Encryption resolved the problem.

> If you are a Dell Employee, and this is happening with you, raise an incident under Service Now and select DDPE as Application.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 8.x to 10.x? Appears these are the only major versions available currently. 

Also please let me know what name this shield service goes by in Services.msc or if there is a separate command line executable.

Answer (score 1):

The Resolution to this is to Install the **Dell Data Encryption Repair Tool**.

This will probably be available in the **Software Center**(for Dell Internal users) or on Dell.com **software downloads** sections(for external users).

Comment: Dell Data Protection | Encryption - Repair Tool is not maintained actively and might not be available for the new users.